# Why my While block can not be Run

Tags: php, sql-server

I try this code to fetch records from database, But my while block cloud not response to me. I echo my query it will print perfect but when copy the query run my server it does not return values. This cod to produced error "Undefined variable: json " because of it ignore While block. Thanks in Adv

```
<?php
    require "db_config.php";

    $cus_name="R M PLASTICES";

    if(isset($cus_name) && $cus_name!=NULL && $cus_name!="")
    {
        $sql="select Vo.Cus_Name,Vo.vendorid,Vo.Created_date,vm.raw_mat as MATERIAL,vm.uom as UOM,vm.qty as ORDERQTY,vm.qtyin as RECDQTY,convert(decimal(7,3),sum(vm.qty-vm.qtyin)) as BALQTY from mmsuser.vendor_mat vm inner join mmsuser.vendor_order vo on vm.vendorid=vo.vendorid where Vo.Cus_Name='".$cus_name."'group by vm.Raw_mat,vm.qty,vm.uom,vm.qtyin,Vo.Cus_Name,Vo.vendorid,vm.id,Vo.Created_date having sum(vm.qty-vm.qtyin) > 0 order by vm.raw_mat";
    }

    $stmt=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    if($stmt===false) 
    {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
    }

    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      $json['purchase_pending_repo'][]=$row;
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

    echo json_encode($json);

    sqlsrv_close($conn);  

?>
```

Comment: You're lucky that you only get "Undefined variable: json". I would also expect occasional "Undefined variable: sql". Advice: define your variables! Put `$json = ['purchase_pending_repo'=>[]]` somewhere before the `while` cycle. Also, are you sure your query returns any rows at all?

Comment: Still i con get any response form while block @jirka

Comment: Are you 100% sure your query returns any rows then? The code seems all right.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to append data in arrays second dimension, without even initializing array first.

First you need to initialize `$json` array variable and second you need to initialize second array in `$json['purchase_pending_repo']`.

```
<?php
    require "db_config.php";

    $cus_name="R M PLASTICES";

    if(isset($cus_name) && $cus_name!=NULL && $cus_name!="")
    {
        $sql="select Vo.Cus_Name,Vo.vendorid,Vo.Created_date,vm.raw_mat as MATERIAL,vm.uom as UOM,vm.qty as ORDERQTY,vm.qtyin as RECDQTY,convert(decimal(7,3),sum(vm.qty-vm.qtyin)) as BALQTY from mmsuser.vendor_mat vm inner join mmsuser.vendor_order vo on vm.vendorid=vo.vendorid where Vo.Cus_Name='".$cus_name."'group by vm.Raw_mat,vm.qty,vm.uom,vm.qtyin,Vo.Cus_Name,Vo.vendorid,vm.id,Vo.Created_date having sum(vm.qty-vm.qtyin) > 0 order by vm.raw_mat";
    }

    $stmt=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    if($stmt===false) 
    {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
    }
    $json = array('purchase_pending_repo' => array()); //OR $json = ['purchase_pending_repo'=>[]]
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      $json['purchase_pending_repo'][]=$row;
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

    echo json_encode($json);

    sqlsrv_close($conn);  

?>
```

Comment: No response form while now just print the  {"purchase_pending_repo":[]} @Gvidas